# Multiple API calls being made when using Async Form Control Validation Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I'm attempting to add async validation via a FormControl and am getting multiple responses for each keypress.  an extra request is being made every time I type/remove a character from the formcontrol.

**basics.component.ts**

```
export class TrainingModuleBasicsComponent implements OnInit, StepperItem<TrainingModule>  {
  trainingModule: FormGroup;
  errorMessages: Object;
  formErrors: Object;
  model: TrainingModule;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private trainingModuleService: TrainingModuleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();
    this.buildValidation();
  }

  buildForm(): void {
    const codeRegex = '[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*';

    this.trainingModule = this.fb.group({
      moduleCode: [this.model.moduleCode, Validators.pattern(codeRegex), [this.validateDuplicateCourseCode.bind(this)]],
      title: [this.model.title, Validators.required],
      description: [this.model.description]
    });
  }

  private validateDuplicateCourseCode(control: AbstractControl) {
    return new Observable((obs: any) => {
      control.valueChanges
                 .debounceTime(400)
                 .distinctUntilChanged()
                 .switchMap(value => this.trainingModuleService.verifyCourseCode(value))
                 .subscribe(
                   data => {
                     console.log('request made');
                     if (!data.error) {
                       obs.next({'duplicateCourseCode': true});
                       obs.complete();
                     } else {
                       obs.next(null);
                       obs.complete();
                     }
                   }
                 );
    });
}
```

**training-module.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class TrainingModuleService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  verifyCourseCode(courseCode: string): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get(environment.rlmsApi + '/Modules/Code/' + courseCode,
                            new RequestOptions({ headers: new RlmsHeaders() })
                        )
                      .map(res => Observable.of(res.json()))
                      .catch(e => Observable.of(e.json()));
  }
```

Comment: What is your question

Comment: the validateDuplicateCourseCode function makes 3 calls upon the first keypress.  After an additional keypress, the function makes 4 calls.  After another keypress, it makes 5 calls and it continues in this fashion.  I only want it to make one request per keypress if the user pauses after keypress (debounceTime).  Instead, it appears that the calls aren't being made until after debounceTime, but they are all called after.

Comment: @JosephWilliams how did you solve the problem ? I actually have a similar issue. When my form is displaying multiple calls is makes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are subscribing to `control.valueChanges`.

I think this is what you want.:

```
private validateDuplicateCourseCode(control: AbstractControl) {
    return new Observable((obs: any) => {
        this.trainingModuleService.verifyCourseCode(control.value)).subscribe(data => {
             console.log('request made');
             if (!data.error) {
                 obs.next({'duplicateCourseCode': true});
                 obs.complete();
             } else {
                 obs.next(null);
                 obs.complete();
             }
         }
     });
});
```